# iptables firewall showing tunnel traffic with ens3 public IPv4 as source

Tags: networking, iptables

I'm seeing very strange iptables logging-rules (in my opinion) for which I can't find an answer / explanation online.

I have the following interfaces on my Linux server:

```
- ens3 with public IP XX.XX.XX.XXX
- ppp0 with public IP YY.YY.YY.YYY which is my VPN IP
```

Now I see this rule in iptables-logging, dropping an outgoing connection that is using the `ppp0` interface, but with the `ens3` IP as source-ip for this packet.

```
Oct 11 16:42:10 ubuntu kernel: [70339.663030] Firewall dropped IPv4: IN= OUT=ppp0 SRC=XX.XX.XX.XXX DST={REMOVED} LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT= 41800 DPT=41891 WINDOW=64296 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
```

How is that possible? I expected the server would use either `ens3` or the `ppp0` interface with the according IP of the interface?

So in this particular case, I would expect the source IP to match the interface `ppp0` public IP, which is `YY.YY.YY.YYY`

Answer (score 0):

Regular IP routing (on Linux and most other systems) is entirely based on the destination address, not the source. Although the routing table on Linux has attributes to influence source address *selection* (when the software has not requested any specific address), the routes are not *matched* against whatever source address was chosen, only against the destination address.<sup>1</sup>

So if you have a program that specifically binds to XX.XX.XX.XXX, its outbound packets will still happily follow the VPN route "`default dev ppp0`" because your VPN client has set it as higher priority than the old default route via eth0.

More commonly, if you *receive* a packet at the public XX.XX.XX.XXX address, any replies that your machine sends will of course have XX.XX.XX.XXX as the source – but that doesn't affect what routes they follow; the higher-priority VPN route will still be chosen.

Some other operating systems will be smarter and choose out of multiple equal-priority routes depending on the source address, e.g. when replying from the Ethernet address they'll prefer a route that goes via eth0, but Linux doesn't do that automatically – it is *possible* to set up, but you have to fiddle with iptables fwmarks and `ip rule` Policy-based Routing rules (already covered in older threads).

---

<sup>1</sup> Linux does support matching routes on (source, destination) but only for IPv6.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. But, I want to force all my outgoing traffic to use the VPN public IP YY.YY.YY.YYY. If I understood you correctly, this is not possible? I've tried all kinds of POSTROUTING set-ups with iptables but none seems to do the trick